# Showing the Difference between 2 sources / queries in Grafana

Tags: sql, sql-server, grafana, grafana-variable

At the minute I have 2 lists of data from 2 different queries and sources, for example I have:

Source 1

```
Red
Blue
White
Green
Black
```

Source 2

```
Red
Blue
Black
```

I want to be able to compare the 2 and show the ones that are missing from Source 2 (White and Green) in a table.

I have tried various options within Transform but can't seem to get it to do what I need.

Comment: `EXCEPT`?......

Comment: One way: NOT EXISTS

Comment: By two different sources, you mean two different data sources in Grafana?

Comment: Yes it's 2 different sources so I can't do a join as such.

Comment: Does your queries return a single column, or are the any additional columns not shown in your example?

Comment: I can get additional columns if needed but the only thing that would match is the "Hostname" which is the column I need to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT S1.Item
FROM Source1 AS S1
LEFT JOIN Source2 AS S2 ON S1.Item = S2.Item
WHERE S2.Item IS NULL
```

Or :

```
SELECT Item
FROM Source1
EXCEPT
SELECT Item
FROM Source2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I can do that in Grafana?

Comment: This solution will work ONLY if both queries are directed to the same data source, and can be replaced with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

In case your actual dataset for second query include something more than a single column:

Use two transformations:

1. "Join by field"

- Mode: OUTER,
- Field: name of column with the same values (columns have to be named the same in both datasets),

2. "Filter data by values"

- Filter type: EXCLUDE,
- Conditions: Match all,
  and add a condition for every column present in dataset 2 (except for the "key" column): `Is null`.

If your actual dataset for second query contains only key fields, you'll need to modify your queries to have additional columns.

For example, it can be done with query

```sql
with t1 as (
  --your original query here
)
select val, val unique2 from t1
-- val here is assumed name of your "key" column
```

Then apply solution described above, with additional Transformation "Organize fields", to hide additional column.